# Integrate an QML application with an C++ application

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, c++17

Is there any way how can I integrate a QML application within one with C++?

---

**WHAT I HAVE?**

I have an application made with **C++** and **ui** files which should be the main application, and also I have another one where has just some screens and views made in **QML**.

---

**THE PROBLEM**

Is there any way in witch I can get the pages writen in QML and access them within the C++ application? The reasone I'm asking this is because I've saw that that the actually main it's totally different.

**C++ main:**

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w(&a);
w.show();
return a.exec();
```

**QML main:**

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

qmlRegisterType<MovieListModel>("MovieListModel", 1, 0, "MovieListModel");
qmlRegisterType<MovieModel>("MovieModel", 1, 0, "MovieModel");


QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));

QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
if (!obj && url == objUrl)
    QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
engine.load(url);

return app.exec();
```

---

**QUESTION**

How can I combine those 2 applications, or it's at even possible to combine them in a way that if in my application I will click on a button to go on a page from an **UI** file (or generated directly from **C++** code) and if I will click on another button to go on an **QML** page?

If any of you knows how can I do this please let me know, because everything which I could find on google it's how to have an **QML** file as ui and to use some **C++** as backend for that specific UI. But nothing regarding how to combine both in terms of UI.

Comment: If you are wondering why you're getting downvotes: you are basically asking if it is possible to do something that you found can be done. You can make a model in C++ that is registered for QML, which makes things happen in your C++ application, it's up to you how you implement it, the sky is the limit

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer after a while myself.

There exist a special QQuickWidget, dedicated to that exact purpose.

```
QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget;
view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("myqmlfile.qml"));
view->show();
```

Comment: Hi if this is the correct answer then mark it as accepted :)